# calculating length using na.omit in R

Tags: r, dataframe

here is my code:

```
data <-setNames(lapply(paste0("80-20 ", file.number,".csv"),read.csv,stringsAsFactors=FALSE),paste(file.number,"participant"))
# imports csv data and turns it into a R-data file

df <- data.frame(RT=1:100,rep.sw=sample(c("sw","rep",100,replace=TRUE)))

(error.sw.c <- lapply(data[control.data],function(df) with(df, na.omit(rep.sw == "sw" & accuracy == "wrong"))))
```

This code scans a bunch of excel file and attributes a value of 'TRUE' every time the accuracy is "wrong" for values labeled "sw." then what I want to do is count the number of true values, and put them in a data frame. This is what I tried:

```
(dataframe.c <- data.frame(switch.rt = sapply(sw.c,mean), repetition.rt = sapply(rep.c,mean), switch.error = sapply(error.sw.c,length), group = rep("control",each=length(control.data))))
```

However, when I do this, it gives me the length of all the values (TRUE & FALSE), not just the TRUE values.

If I do this:

```
length(error.sw.c)
```

I get the total of all the error values, not all the error values separately.

So my question is: Is there a way to get the length of each individual excel file so I can put it in a dataframe? Thank you StackOverflow community, you folks haven't let me down yet. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if any clarification is needed. :)

Comment: Not super clear on what you're trying to accomplish but if you just need to count the number of `TRUE` values, `sum()` will work. Sorry if I'm misinterpreting

Comment: Haha, wow that was way easier than expected -thanks so much. If you want, you should answer the question below so I can credit you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum()` can be used to count the number of `TRUE`s in a logical vector. Let's see why:

```
set.seed(555)
logicalVec <- rnorm(5) > 0 # create logical vector
logicalVec
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Arithmetic functions coerce logical values to numeric values such that `FALSE` becomes `0` and `TRUE` becomes `1`:

```
logicalVec*1
[1] 0 1 1 1 0
```

You can think of `sum(logicalVec)` as equivalent to `sum(c(0,1,1,1,0))`:

```
sum(c(0,1,1,1,0))
[1] 3
sum(logicalVec)
[1] 3
```